# xsl:value-of adjacent element

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, xsl-fo

I am creating some xsl-fo templates for the first time. The XML source file for the data has custom fields like these (there are several hundred)

```
<CustomField InternalRef="">
      <Module>ModuleName2</Module>
      <Name>NameOfUserDefinedField2</Name>
      <Value>ValueOfUserDefinedField2</Value>
    </CustomField>

<CustomField InternalRef="MyRef">
      <Module>ModuleName</Module>
      <Name>NameOfUserDefinedField</Name>
      <Value>ValueOfUserDefinedField</Value>
    </CustomField>
```

The record with an attribute i am retrieving like this in my xsl stylesheet.

```
<xsl:value-of select="/BaseElement/CustomFields/CustomField[@InternalRef='MyRef']/Value"/>
```

Where the element doesnt have the attribute I would appreciate any suggestions of the appropriate path to use.

The value i'm trying to extract is ValueOfUserDefinedField2; from the custom field where there isn't a value in the attribute

Comment: You speak of "adjacent element", but it's hard to see what exactly that means in your situation. In general you can use the `preceding-sibling` or the `following-sibling` axis to select adjacent elements - for example: `<xsl:value-of select="/BaseElement/CustomFields/CustomField[@InternalRef='MyRef']/preceding-sibling::CustomField[1]/Value"/>`.

Comment: The value i'm trying to extract is ValueOfUserDefinedField2; where there isnt a value in the attribute. Have updated the question

Comment: Actually, there is a value in the attribute: the value is the zero-length string, and you can select it the same way as any other element, using `CustomField[@InternalRef='']`. Now, if there are two elements with the same value, that's a problem (and it applies whether the value is the zero-length string or anything else); but we can't tell you how to handle that without knowing your data.